# Making a proportion table for the same variables against each other in R by satisfying a condition

Tags: r

I have a very large data frame like this
Let's say we have only 8 people in the data frame, showed in R code below

Noted the each row in 'df' represents an individual person

```
football <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
basketball <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1)
other <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

df<- data.frame(football, basketball, other)
```

I am trying to get a table like this one, using football (or any other variable in the data frame) as the "reference"

```
mytable <- matrix (c(1, 0.5, 0.25 ,0.66, 1, 0.33, 1, 1, 1), byrow=T, ncol=3)
colnames(mytable) <- c("football","basketball","other")
rownames(mytable) <- c("football","basketball","other")
```

In this case,

4 out of 8 people play football: 
4 of out 4 people who play football play football (100%), 2 out of 4 people football players also play basketball (50%), 1 out of 4 football players also plays other sports (25%).

3 out of 8 people play basketball:
 2 out of 3 basketball players also play football (66%), 3 out of 3 people who play basketball play basketball (100%), 1 out of 3 basketball players also play other sports (33%)

1 out of 8 people play other sports:
1 out of 1 also plays football (100%), 1 out of 1 play basketball (100%), 1 out of 1 people play other play other (100%),

Also, is there a way to graph table like this (it's okay if this question is not answered, but ideas would be appreciated)

Comment: Try `prop.table(tcrossprod(table(rep(names(df), each = nrow(df)), unlist(df))))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But the code did not return me the desired output and I'm not sure what the output represents (e.g. football returned as 0.1 across all variables, the other values ranged between 0.1 and 0.16)

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with some matrix operations:

```
m = as.matrix(df)
t(m) %*% m / colSums(m)
#             football basketball     other
# football   1.0000000        0.5 0.2500000
# basketball 0.6666667        1.0 0.3333333
# other      1.0000000        1.0 1.0000000
```

As for plotting, a heatmap can be a nice approach. Simply:

```
gplots::heatmap.2(result, dendrogram = "none", Rowv = F, Colv = F)
```

[image]

For more flexibility, I'd recommend using `ggplot2`. [This question should get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726447/903061).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I am looking for. And, yes, there is typo in my question. It should be 1 indeed, I have corrected it.

Comment: I'm curious, Gregor, ... how did you see this? What sort of applications might you have seen for this use of matrix-multiply on logical matrices holding "attribute maps"?

Comment: @42- I... can't really say. It reminded me a bit of the [page rank algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank), just with all the weights being 1, which was covered in an old linear algebra class in undergrad. I wasn't sure it would work until I tried it, but when starting with a N x M matrix, and wanting an M x M matrix result, multiplying by the transpose seemed like a promising start. When I did `t(m) %*% m`, it was clear it was the concurrent counts, and it was easy from there.

Comment: Experimental programming. Coding by analogy. A method I often use.